# Are questions about astrology on-topic on any SE site?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Is there any site on Stack Exchange where I can ask questions about astrology or the zodiac?

This has been asked at the Mythology site,  [Tags astrology and zodiac](https://mythology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/331/tags-astrology-and-zodiac), where I responded with the following, which questions whether *a new site* should be created:

> Astrology has different goals than mythology because it intends to
> draw conclusions about reality, like science does. It shares similar
> purposes and procedures to **numerology**. Both are forms of
> **symbolism** that try to find patterns from repetitions in nature. They frequently deal with **spirituality**. I think
> *"pseudo-scientific"* is a loosely accurate description of the field; it
> should be improved by identifying what impels the field.

Answer (score 14):

You [can ask about Hindu Astrology](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72/are-questions-regarding-hindu-astrology-allowed-here) on the [Hinduism Stack Exchange](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com) site.

Past that, nowhere, mostly because the topic hasn't attracted a lot of interest on Area 51, where there have been 14 different proposals either directly about Astrology or at least encompassing it - one is still open now and [12 of which never attracted enough followers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K8SR9.png).

- [Paranormal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/114464/paranormal)

Any other site out there that does accept Astrology-related questions would only accept them in the context of that site (such as with Mythology), and would not accept any general questions about Astrology which is what I'm assuming you are hoping for.

Comment: [Skeptics.SE] also takes [some questions about astrology](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/astrology), though only from a certain point of view, and that's probably not the one that OP is looking for either.

Comment: @Josh I imagine the answers to astrology questions on Skeptics are mainly along the lines of "it's all rubbish", which isn't what someone who's actually interested in astrology will want to hear.

Comment: Right, that's why I said "that's probably not the [point of view] that OP is looking for".

Answer (score 1):

There is also an Area 51 proposal for a [Fringe Science](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/102268/fringe-science) site that might accept questions on Astrology. Astrology isn't mentioned specifically by name in the proposal's list of example topics that are often considered pseudosciences, but that list is exemplary, not exhaustive. To the extent that Astrology can be studied in a fringe science context, it could fit there.

Comment: From reading the proposal description I don't think they appreciate them being called pseudosciences

Comment: It's been deleted.